# Control Screen with Python

Tags: python, controls, screen, keyboard-shortcuts

is there a way to control the screen/monitor with python, like for example turn it off an on again (comparable to the shortcut-buttons on laptop keyboards)?

Thank you!

Comment: Windows...sorry for not mentioning it before

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most modern laptops have a physical connection between the button and the monitor.
For instance, my Dell precision i can boot the PC and dimm my display even before BIOS launches which tells me, it's wired via hardware connections.

With that sad, i can still emulate a few system-calls from within the OS to execute the task as well, not just as energy efficient as pressing the actual button.

Doing this requires you to (on windows) use `pywin32` to connect to the appropriate system api's and execute a very specific command to do so, and it is tricky if you're not familar with System API's and calling the windows 32 functions.

Something along the lines of:

```
import os, win32com.client

def runScreensaver():
    strComputer = "."
    objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
    colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Desktop")
    for objItem in colItems:
        if objItem.ScreenSaverExecutable:
            os.system(objItem.ScreenSaverExecutable + " /start")
            break
```

If you're on **linux** you can try to just execute `os.system()` one of the following:

- [How to change the Monitor brightness on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625836/how-to-change-the-monitor-brightness-on-linux)
- [Adjust screen brightness/contrast in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421356/adjust-screen-brightness-contrast-in-python)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight

Comment: I'm using windows with python 32 bit and I downloaded and installed pywin32. Now if I run your code, I get an error saying:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/screensaver.py", line 1, in <module>            What else do I have to do?
    import os, win32com.client
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: No module named 'win32api'                         What else do I do wrong?

Comment: yes I did...it still doesnt't work this way, but don't worry I realized that for my purpose the automatic build in sleep mode is good enough :)

Comment: @Torxed I think you are talking about `os.system()`?

Answer (score 5):

In python

```
    import win32gui
    import win32con

    #to turn off use :-
    win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST,
                     win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)
    #turn on use :-
    win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST,
                     win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this in linux:

```
def set_brightness(brightness):
    if int(brightness) > 15:
        raise TypeError("Need int 0 < and > 15")
    elif int(brightness) < 0:
        raise TypeError("Need int 0 < and > 15")
    with open("/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness","w") as bright:
         bright.write(str(brightness))
         bright.close()
set_brightness(0) #Brightness 0-15
```