# Turn screen on and off on Windows

Tags: python, windows, winapi, screen, ctypes

Directly into the problem, I was trying to implement the screen/display/monitor Off and On feature into my primary program. I researched a bit and found [this one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334665/15136959) interesting. So, tried testing it. Here's the code in a nutshell:

```
import time
import win32gui
import win32con

def ScreenOFF():
    """
    Function to turn off the screen.
    """
    return win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST,
                            win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)

def ScreenON():
    """
    Function to turn on the screen.
    """
    return win32gui.SendMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST,
                            win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)

ScreenOFF()
time.sleep(5)
ScreenON()
time.sleep(5)
```

The Screen Off was working great but while executing the Screen On function, **The Screen only turns on for a second and then again it turns off immediately**. I could not even reason now why that happens !

Also tried this more primitive approach but here too is the same problem:

```
import time
import ctypes

def ScreenOFF():
    """
    Function to turn off the screen.
    """
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, 2)

def ScreenON():
    """
    Function to turn on the screen.
    """
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, -1)

ScreenOFF()
time.sleep(5)
ScreenON()
```

Here's [another reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48739720/15136959) that might help here.

There are github repos on screen off, [like this one](https://github.com/arjun024/turn-off-screen), but NONE on Screen On !

Please suggest me if there are any fixes to this or other better ways to turn the screen On/OFF ?

Comment: Any answer suggesting HWND_BROADCAST is incorrect.

Comment: You can pass 1 as parameter. It is for low power, but it will work. Most answers around suggest to fake a mouse movement.

Comment: Passing 1 does not seem to work on my laptop, and I also tried faking mouse movement using `pyautogui.move(1,1)`, but that does work either...

Comment: If possible, please upvote this question to reach as many users as possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a actual solution to the issue where it just turns as soon as it turns on, but I found a way to keep it not going off.

Not a very great way but it works

```py
import time
import ctypes
import win32api, win32con
def screen_off():
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, 2)
def screen_on():
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, -1)
    move_cursor()
def move_cursor():
    x, y = (0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y)

screen_off()
time.sleep(3)
screen_on()
```

If you move the cursor or type something the screen will stay on, so

Comment: for me on my laptop the code works perfectly as intended. The use of `win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y)` instead of `pyautogui.move(1,1)` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks... `win32api` does the Trick :>

Comment: Is it possible to only turn off one specific monitor? For instance: I have 3Monitors, would I be able to write a Python script to only turn off the lateral two?

Answer (score 0):

There is a python package called [monitorcontrol](https://github.com/newAM/monitorcontrol) that you can use to control monitor power mode, contrast, input source and brightness (luminance).
Here is example to power on and off monitor:

```py
from monitorcontrol import get_monitors
from time import sleep

for monitor in get_monitors():
     with monitor:
         monitor.set_power_mode(4) # soft off
         sleep(3)
         monitor.set_power_mode(1) # on
```

If you want to use ctypes instead of this package see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065609/10308458) to turn on and off the monitor with ctypes and windows monitor api

Answer (score 0):

I didn't come up with anything new. Just building on to the other answer, you can simulate mouse event to turn the screen on automatically.

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time
import ctypes
import win32api, win32con


def screen_off():
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, 2)
def screen_on():
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW(65535, 274, 61808, -1)
    move_cursor()

def move_cursor():
    x, y = (0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y)
    mouse = Controller()
    x,y = mouse.position
    mouse.move(x+1, y+1)

screen_off()
time.sleep(3)
screen_on()
```

I'm using this as my workaround monitorcontrol module. It is great, but as at v 3.1.0 it doesn't work when you want to turn off all monitors at once that share hmonitor (i.e., two monitors duplicating the same screen).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem. I have an Alienware Notebook with backlighting on my keyboard and with both `win32gui.SendMessage`, `win32gui.PostMessage` they both shut off my screen and my keyboard backlighting. They both stop python from running. `win32api.SendMessage` does the same thing.

The one that worked was `win32api.PostMessage`. `win32api.PostMessage` shut my screen off without turning my keyboard backlighting off and python keeps running.

```py
import time
import win32api
import win32con

def ScreenOFF():
    """
    Function to turn off the screen.
    """
    return win32api.PostMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST,
                            win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, 2)

def ScreenON():
    """
    Function to turn on the screen.
    """
    return win32api.PostMessage(win32con.HWND_BROADCAST,
                            win32con.WM_SYSCOMMAND, win32con.SC_MONITORPOWER, -1)

ScreenOFF()
time.sleep(5)
ScreenON()
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I tested my own code with the win32api.PostMessage and it works but some time tonight while I was at work my keyboard shut off, and when it python stopped responding.

Comment: I've been paying around with this for months, and it is obvious to me that whatever you use, python or CMD.exe that it never works. Python always freezes. I do know that if you let the monitors power off on their own from the windows settings, you don't have the problem with python freezing. It is hardware dependent 'cause I don't have this problem on my G7. I only have this problem on my Alienware.